# Conditionally retrieve fields from elasticsearch _source based on value of another field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type with a field indicating if to reveal another field. For example, for a document, if ifRevealAge is true, value of the age field should be retrieved from _source and included in query result for the document. If ifRevealAge is false, then age field should not be included in the query result for the document. Is it possible by query API?

If it is not, how to do it through java API? I think the method toXContent(XContentBuilder builder, ToXContent.Params params) of GetResponse is supposed to do so but I can't find any documentation or references for how to use the method for filtering / modifying response result conditionally. The api documentation is just too concise.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible either way, meaning from Elasticsearch point of view you cannot create a query to retrieve or not something from `_source` based on a value from another field. You can retrieve the age no matter what and then in your app you display/use that field or not.

Comment: My frontend is a web app. I don't want to expose sensitive conditional field to frontend at all if it is set not to be revealed. So I am thinking of using Java API to retrieve documents, then use XContentBuilders to parse responses and do filtering, then build the JSON response for frontend. But I have no luck to find any references about how to use XContentBuilder for filtering.